# i need to make the button randomize and then display on a 4-segment

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

That is my main code, in the void loop i want to make it so there is a rand function that the button activates, then it goes into the sevseg.setNumber section to be displayed. I'm trying to make a 20-sided die, so the rand function would be 1-20. I'm not really sure what to do, can i get some help?

```
#include "SevSeg.h"
SevSeg sevseg; 


const int  BUTTON = 1;    
int buttonState = 0;          
int lastButtonState = LOW;   

void setup(){
  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {10, 11, 12, 13};
  byte segmentPins[] = {9, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4};

  bool resistorsOnSegments = true; 
  bool updateWithDelaysIn = true;
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE; 
  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, 
resistorsOnSegments);
  sevseg.setBrightness(150);

  pinMode(BUTTON, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lastButtonState = LOW;
}

void loop(){
  sevseg.setNumber();
  sevseg.refreshDisplay();
  if (digitalRead (BUTTON) == HIGH)
  {
    rand() % 20 + 1;
  }
}
```

I changed buttonPin to BUTTON, now  I need to figure out how to put the rand value inside of sevseg.setNumber's parenthesis.

Comment: Is this code for an Arduino? Then please [edit] your question to add the `arduino` tag. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Some programmer dude It is for arduino, im just confused about making it work right, also, I'm new to the C++ world, I was hoping that I could get some help.

Comment: For the random number generation check out [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) site which shows how to generate a random number in a certain range using `rand`. However, please note that `rand` does not emit a perfect uniform distribution, thus if you are working with C++11 or higher you should use [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: okay, i fixed the `rand` function, now i need to know how to make the `rand` value display

Comment: @Ihave7000hats You're not capturing the return-value of your call to `rand()` in a variable. Not sure since i don't know much about arduino-functions, but can't you just do `sevseg.setNumber(rand()%20 +1)`?

Comment: @melk When i do that it reads a constantly changing value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main-loop like this:

```
void loop(){

  if (digitalRead (BUTTON) == HIGH)
  {
    if (!high) {//<-- make sure it only changes the value the first time
      sevseg.setNumber(rand() % 20 + 1);
      sevseg.refreshDisplay();
      high = true
    }
  }
  else {
    high = false;//<-- reset high to false when the button isn't pressed anymore
  } 
}
```

Don't forget to declare `bool high = false;` in your definition-section.

Comment: thanks! :) I'm really glad I could get some help with this! now I've got to make the actual display work, It seems that it can do numbers higher than 9, I'll fix it.